# How to add reset button in contact form

Tags: drupal

Below mentioned code is not working

```
function yourModuleName_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ((strpos($form_id, 'contact_mail_page') === 0)) {
    $form['reset'] = array(
      '#value' => '<input class="form-button" type="reset" value=" Reset " />',
      '#weight' => 1001,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option1**
If you want to use custom html you should use 'markup' or 'item' form element

```
$form['reset'] = array(
  '#type' => 'markup'
  '#markup' => '<input class="form-button" type="reset" value=" Reset " />',
  '#weight' => 1001,
);
```

**Option 2** Use javascript and button

```
$form['actions']['reset'] = array(
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => t('Reset'),
  '#weight' => 1001,
  '#validate' => array(),
  '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'this.form.reset(); return false;'),
);
```

**Optoin 3** You can add link to the same page and style it like a button

```
$form['reset'] = array(
   '#type' => 'markup'
   '#markup' => '<a href="/contact">' .t('Reset') . '<a/>',
   '#weight' => 1001,
);
```

**Option 4** Add submit or button that will do nothing on submit.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```
$form['reset'] = array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => '<input type="reset" value="Reset All Values" class="form-submit">',
    );
```

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

switch ($form_id) {

case 'myform':
  $form['buttons']['reset_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#value' => '<input class="form-button" value="Reset" type="reset">',
    '#weight' => 2000,
  );
  break;
 }

return $form;

}
```